# Order of phase transition in random walks

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, stochastic-processes

If we consider a random walk with step size distribution $P(s)\sim s^{-\gamma}$, we know the order of $\langle s^2\rangle$ changes at $\gamma=3$, while the order of $\langle s\rangle$ changes at $\gamma=2$. I was just wondering if it is right to say these are phase transitions? If so, is it possible to determine which order of phase transition? Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE! What do you mean by "order" exactly?

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thanks. I was trying to understand something like if it is first-order phase transition or second-order phase transition or whatever.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. What do you mean by "the order of $\langle s^2 \rangle$ changes"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, let me know if it is still unclear. For example, if we look at the location after $n$ steps, $s_n$. We know $\langle s_n\rangle\sim n$ for $\gamma>2$, but $\langle s_n\rangle\sim n^{1/(\gamma-1)}$ for $\gamma<2$